# Capture output of non-terminating process into a variable

Tags: bash

I suspect this has been asked and answered before but I'm not sure if I've searched correctly.

I have a non-terminating process (a server) which outputs a single line with its url and port when it starts. I want to capture that line into a variable so I can pass it to other programs.

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```bash
% export URL=`server start` &
```

However it's not setting `URL` because (I think :-)) `server` is non-terminating and still running.

How can I capture the URL printed by `server` into a variable so I can use it elsewhere?

Comment: Can you send the output to a file and read from the file instead?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would that be done? Using ">>" or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do:

```
server start &
cat /proc/${!}/fd/1
```

This starts server and $! returns it's id. fd/1 is a stdout of process available via /proc

NOTE: there should be no other line code between start and $!  as it might return another process id

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

1. Create a FIFO (named pipe). If you need to hide it from other users, use `mktemp -d` beforehand to create a temporary directory and create the FIFO there (for brevity this answer does not do this).

   ```
   mkfifo myfifo
   ```
2. We're going to let the server process write to the FIFO; we're going to let the script read from the FIFO. After starting the server, opening the FIFO for reading and then closing (so there are no readers left) will cause SIGPIPE be sent to the server process; so it's good to open the FIFO for reading beforehand and keep it open. On the other hand, opening the FIFO beforehand *solely* for reading will block, waiting for some process to open the FIFO for writing. To solve this, open the FIFO for reading and writing, and don't close the descriptor until later:

   ```
   exec 3<>myfifo
   ```
3. Start the server in the background and let it write to the FIFO:

   ```
   server start >&3 &
   ```

   (`>&3` and `>myfifo` are technically different; for us either form will work here).
4. Read exactly one line from the FIFO:

   ```
   <&3 IFS= read -r URL
   ```

   (`<&3` and `<myfifo` are technically different; for us either form will work here).
5. Start `cat` in the background to let the process print to whatever the stdout of the script is (or redirect the output of this `cat` to `/dev/null` or whatever; adjust to your needs). Omitting this step will cause `server` to block if it prints too much to the FIFO. You won't need this `cat` only if you are totally sure the process prints nothing more after what you `read`; even then the `cat` will do no harm.

   In general there's also another concern: `server` may exit because of SIGPIPE after we close all descriptors open for reading. Our `server` itself holds the descriptor for writing *and* reading, so SIGPIPE cannot happen. If it could happen then starting `cat` that reads from the FIFO would solve the problem.

   Start `cat` then:

   ```
   <myfifo cat 3>&- &
   ```

   Note here we separately open `myfifo` for reading and we don't allow `cat` to inherit the descriptor that allows writing. The point is `cat` mustn't hold the FIFO open for writing. This will be important in a moment.
6. Close the descriptor, so only `cat` and `server` hold the FIFO open. You can also unlink the FIFO (this will not interrupt the processes using it):

   ```
   exec 3>&-
   rm myfifo
   ```

   This way no future descendant of your script will inherit the descriptor.
7. Work with `$URL`.
8. When `server` exits, there will be no other process holding the FIFO opened for writing, `cat` will encounter the EOF condition and exit. This is when the way we started `cat` matters. If `cat` held the inherited file descriptor, formally it would be a writer to the FIFO, so it couldn't exit automatically. We ensured `cat` will exit automatically after our `server` exits.

   At the end of your script you may want to `wait` for this to happen:

   ```
   wait
   ```

   (this assumes there are no other background jobs). Without this `wait` the script may exit before `server`, leaving `server` and `cat` in the background. Decide if you want the script to `wait` or not.

---

#### Proof of concept

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# fake server
server() {
   echo 'example.com'
   for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do echo 'server running'; sleep 1; done
}

mkfifo myfifo
exec 3<>myfifo

server start >&3 &
<&3 IFS= read -r URL
<myfifo cat 3>&- &

exec 3>&-
rm myfifo

echo "The URL is $URL"
sleep 2
echo "Still working with $URL"
sleep 2
echo "Done. Waiting for the server to close."
wait
```